# Parser, regexp match MM:SS + MM:SS format

Tags: regex, parsing, match

I want to extract information

```
MM:SS +MM:SS '__string____'
time +extra time and the information after it.
```

Everytime new pattern is detected it must start from new line. 
So far the above code works in that way, but it is not matching all the time instances.

Once MM:SS finishes then extra time starts MM:SS + MM:SS

it can also take form 120:34 +3:22

```
idx = regexp(l,'(\d+:\d+|+\d+:\d+)(\D+)*','match');
```

Comment: For one you need to escape the `+` character to match a literal. Something [like this](http://regex101.com/r/gK6iK4/1)?

Comment: This pattern gives the same result as the code before
But many time instants are skipped. 
Can I share a text file here?

Comment: Its a complete text files, I am also new to stack over flow. I think it can't be attached

http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/football/27990605

I have taken contents from here. CTRL+A copied into a text file, Ensuring all the text commentary is captured.

Comment: Infact , '(\d+:\d+)((+\d+:\d+)|(\D+))*' this also gives me the same result as code I shared before.

Comment: Thank You so much for your guidance. Its really helpful.
I needed to extract the MM:SS +MM:SS 'string' 
to 0:00 ' String'. In short complete text commentary. 
I'll test this on my txt file, and try to make amendments if necessary.

Comment: This http://regex101.com/ doesn't support MATLAB?

Comment: Well, I haven't seen any online tester supporting MATLAB. Weird...

Comment: @hex494D49 - Because MATLAB is licensed software :(.  There are online Octave interpreters, which is essentially a free portover of MATLAB, but MATLAB is not free, and hence that's why there are no online testers *thumbs down*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression.

```
^|\s|.*?(\d+:\d+\s\+\d+:\d+).*?|\s|$
```

It will match any MM:SS +MM:SS sequence anywhere within a text block

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP9zY3/3)